# cross validation and validation( to find RMS error and correlation ) in matlab

Tags: correlation, cross-validation, matlab, validation, rms

**Dear Experts**;

i have text data (**sample points are 324**) of different climatic parameters. 3rd column of each text file was contained some missing or NaN data. Using [Scatter data interpolation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html) in matlab, i have filled these NaN values with n**earest, natural and bilinear interpolation techniques.**

**I want to check which interpolation technique will be best suited for my data and if suited then how much?**

On searching i found **cross validation and validation(NOT SURE WHETHER IT PROVIDE ME CORRECT SOLUTION OF MY PROBLEM?)** which can provide me **RMS error and correlation(if any other parameters possible tell me please)** among different interpolation techniques.Through checking RMS error and correlation i shall select which will be **best interpolation technique** for my data set.

**My data set look like this** (first column is Latitude, Second is Longitude and third is temperature which NaN value has been filled by bilinear interpolation)

```
21.500  60.500  295.867 
21.500  61.500  295.828 
21.500  62.500  295.828 
21.500  63.500  295.867 
21.500  64.500  296.102 
21.500  65.500  296.234 
21.500  66.500  296.352 
21.500  67.500  296.336 
21.500  68.500  296.305 
21.500  69.500  298.281 
21.500  70.500  301.828 
21.500  71.500  302.094 
21.500  72.500  299.469 
21.500  73.500  301.711 
21.500  74.500  302.317 
21.500  75.500  302.757 
21.500  76.500  303.030 
21.500  77.500  303.137 
21.500  78.500  303.078 
22.500  60.500  295.477 
22.500  61.500  295.484 
22.500  62.500  295.516 
22.500  63.500  295.547 
22.500  64.500  295.852 
22.500  65.500  295.859 
22.500  66.500  295.852 
22.500  67.500  295.711 
22.500  68.500  295.969 
22.500  69.500  298.562 
22.500  70.500  300.828 
22.500  71.500  302.352 
22.500  72.500  300.570 
22.500  73.500  301.383 
22.500  74.500  301.311 
22.500  75.500  301.381 
22.500  76.500  301.692 
22.500  77.500  301.837 
22.500  78.500  301.814 
23.500  60.500  294.906 
23.500  61.500  294.898 
23.500  62.500  295.000 
23.500  63.500  295.078 
23.500  64.500  295.297 
23.500  65.500  295.359 
23.500  66.500  295.297 
23.500  67.500  295.312 
23.500  68.500  296.664 
23.500  69.500  298.781 
23.500  70.500  299.211 
23.500  71.500  300.109 
23.500  72.500  301.000 
23.500  73.500  301.594 
23.500  74.500  302.000 
23.500  75.500  300.911 
23.500  76.500  300.520 
23.500  77.500  300.702 
23.500  78.500  300.718 
24.500  60.500  294.578 
24.500  61.500  294.516 
24.500  62.500  294.734 
24.500  63.500  294.789 
24.500  64.500  294.844 
24.500  65.500  294.562 
24.500  66.500  294.734 
24.500  67.500  296.367 
24.500  68.500  297.438 
24.500  69.500  298.531 
24.500  70.500  298.453 
24.500  71.500  299.195 
24.500  72.500  300.062 
24.500  73.500  300.351 
24.500  74.500  301.055 
24.500  75.500  300.958 
24.500  76.500  300.512 
24.500  77.500  299.734 
24.500  78.500  299.787 
25.500  60.500  296.258 
25.500  61.500  296.391 
25.500  62.500  296.672 
25.500  63.500  296.398 
25.500  64.500  295.773 
25.500  65.500  295.812 
25.500  66.500  296.609 
25.500  67.500  297.977 
25.500  68.500  297.109 
25.500  69.500  297.828 
25.500  70.500  298.430 
25.500  71.500  298.836 
25.500  72.500  298.703 
25.500  73.500  300.207 
25.500  74.500  300.110 
25.500  75.500  300.013 
25.500  76.500  299.917 
25.500  77.500  299.470 
25.500  78.500  299.023 
26.500  60.500  294.484 
26.500  61.500  298.266 
26.500  62.500  296.773 
26.500  63.500  296.892 
26.500  64.500  297.012 
26.500  65.500  297.131 
26.500  66.500  297.250 
26.500  67.500  296.188 
26.500  68.500  295.938 
26.500  69.500  296.906 
26.500  70.500  297.828 
26.500  71.500  299.312 
26.500  72.500  299.359 
26.500  73.500  299.262 
26.500  74.500  299.165 
26.500  75.500  299.069 
26.500  76.500  298.972 
26.500  77.500  298.875 
26.500  78.500  296.773 
27.500  60.500  292.710 
27.500  61.500  295.880 
27.500  62.500  294.643 
27.500  63.500  295.710 
27.500  64.500  296.362 
27.500  65.500  296.333 
27.500  66.500  296.452 
27.500  67.500  295.352 
27.500  68.500  295.148 
27.500  69.500  295.750 
27.500  70.500  295.750 
27.500  71.500  296.070 
27.500  72.500  295.227 
27.500  73.500  297.534 
27.500  74.500  297.437 
27.500  75.500  297.340 
27.500  76.500  297.870 
27.500  77.500  297.405 
27.500  78.500  296.609 
28.500  60.500  290.935 
28.500  61.500  293.494 
28.500  62.500  292.513 
28.500  63.500  293.580 
28.500  64.500  294.647 
28.500  65.500  295.715 
28.500  66.500  295.951 
28.500  67.500  295.773 
28.500  68.500  295.375 
28.500  69.500  295.438 
28.500  70.500  294.664 
28.500  71.500  294.906 
28.500  72.500  294.812 
28.500  73.500  295.805 
28.500  74.500  296.335 
28.500  75.500  296.864 
28.500  76.500  296.731 
28.500  77.500  294.557 
28.500  78.500  294.696 
29.500  60.500  289.161 
29.500  61.500  291.108 
29.500  62.500  290.383 
29.500  63.500  291.450 
29.500  64.500  292.517 
29.500  65.500  293.585 
29.500  66.500  294.652 
29.500  67.500  295.719 
29.500  68.500  296.797 
29.500  69.500  293.375 
29.500  70.500  294.305 
29.500  71.500  294.070 
29.500  72.500  293.750 
29.500  73.500  295.539 
29.500  74.500  295.859 
29.500  75.500  296.057 
29.500  76.500  292.532 
29.500  77.500  292.799 
29.500  78.500  292.924 
30.500  60.500  287.387 
30.500  61.500  288.722 
30.500  62.500  288.253 
30.500  63.500  289.320 
30.500  64.500  290.387 
30.500  65.500  291.455 
30.500  66.500  292.522 
30.500  67.500  292.884 
30.500  68.500  294.198 
30.500  69.500  295.394 
30.500  70.500  293.320 
30.500  71.500  292.930 
30.500  72.500  293.570 
30.500  73.500  294.648 
30.500  74.500  295.383 
30.500  75.500  290.535 
30.500  76.500  290.929 
30.500  77.500  291.182 
30.500  78.500  291.294 
31.500  60.500  285.613 
31.500  61.500  286.336 
31.500  62.500  286.123 
31.500  63.500  287.190 
31.500  64.500  288.257 
31.500  65.500  289.325 
31.500  66.500  289.239 
31.500  67.500  290.049 
31.500  68.500  291.364 
31.500  69.500  292.678 
31.500  70.500  293.992 
31.500  71.500  293.422 
31.500  72.500  294.438 
31.500  73.500  294.141 
31.500  74.500  288.564 
31.500  75.500  289.087 
31.500  76.500  289.468 
31.500  77.500  289.707 
31.500  78.500  289.805 
32.500  60.500  283.839 
32.500  61.500  283.950 
32.500  62.500  283.993 
32.500  63.500  285.060 
32.500  64.500  286.127 
32.500  65.500  286.272 
32.500  66.500  285.726 
32.500  67.500  287.214 
32.500  68.500  288.529 
32.500  69.500  289.843 
32.500  70.500  291.847 
32.500  71.500  294.312 
32.500  72.500  294.812 
32.500  73.500  286.621 
32.500  74.500  287.271 
32.500  75.500  287.781 
32.500  76.500  288.148 
32.500  77.500  288.374 
32.500  78.500  288.458 
33.500  60.500  282.065 
33.500  61.500  281.564 
33.500  62.500  281.863 
33.500  63.500  282.930 
33.500  64.500  283.306 
33.500  65.500  282.759 
33.500  66.500  282.405 
33.500  67.500  284.380 
33.500  68.500  285.694 
33.500  69.500  287.238 
33.500  70.500  289.703 
33.500  71.500  291.025 
33.500  72.500  284.704 
33.500  73.500  285.483 
33.500  74.500  286.120 
33.500  75.500  286.616 
33.500  76.500  286.970 
33.500  77.500  287.182 
33.500  78.500  287.253 
34.500  60.500  280.290 
34.500  61.500  279.178 
34.500  62.500  279.733 
34.500  63.500  280.339 
34.500  64.500  279.792 
34.500  65.500  279.246 
34.500  66.500  279.278 
34.500  67.500  281.545 
34.500  68.500  282.859 
34.500  69.500  285.093 
34.500  70.500  287.237 
34.500  71.500  282.814 
34.500  72.500  283.722 
34.500  73.500  284.487 
34.500  74.500  285.111 
34.500  75.500  285.593 
34.500  76.500  285.933 
34.500  77.500  286.132 
34.500  78.500  286.189 
35.500  60.500  278.516 
35.500  61.500  276.792 
35.500  62.500  277.373 
35.500  63.500  276.826 
35.500  64.500  276.279 
35.500  65.500  275.732 
35.500  66.500  276.150 
35.500  67.500  278.710 
35.500  68.500  280.484 
35.500  69.500  283.450 
35.500  70.500  280.952 
35.500  71.500  281.987 
35.500  72.500  282.881 
35.500  73.500  283.633 
35.500  74.500  284.243 
35.500  75.500  284.712 
35.500  76.500  285.039 
35.500  77.500  285.224 
35.500  78.500  285.267 
36.500  60.500  276.742 
36.500  61.500  274.406 
36.500  62.500  273.859 
36.500  63.500  273.313 
36.500  64.500  272.766 
36.500  65.500  272.219 
36.500  66.500  273.023 
36.500  67.500  275.875 
36.500  68.500  279.662 
36.500  69.500  279.117 
36.500  70.500  280.280 
36.500  71.500  281.302 
36.500  72.500  282.182 
36.500  73.500  282.920 
36.500  74.500  283.517 
36.500  75.500  283.972 
36.500  76.500  284.285 
36.500  77.500  284.457 
36.500  78.500  284.487 
37.500  60.500  277.406 
37.500  61.500  277.547 
37.500  62.500  276.375 
37.500  63.500  275.484 
37.500  64.500  276.820 
37.500  65.500  275.312 
37.500  66.500  274.875 
37.500  67.500  275.875 
37.500  68.500  277.308 
37.500  69.500  278.600 
37.500  70.500  279.750 
37.500  71.500  280.758 
37.500  72.500  281.624 
37.500  73.500  282.349 
37.500  74.500  282.932 
37.500  75.500  283.374 
37.500  76.500  283.674 
37.500  77.500  283.832 
37.500  78.500  283.849
```

Any suggestions, comments, and how to do this in matlab, will be highly appreciable. I am totally new to matlab

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three major parameters you can use in order to judge the goodness of an interpolation scheme:

1. Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE)
   $RMSE = \sqrt{\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-y_i)^2}{N}}$
   where $N$ is the number of patterns in your dataset, $x_i$ is the $i$th pattern and $y_i$ is its estimate (according to a given model, e.g. linear interpolation).
   In Matlab form, if `data` is the actual dataset and `datahat` is its estimate, you can do something like:

   `N=size(data,1); %eval number of rows (i.e. patterns)`
   `RMSE=sqrt(sum((data(:)-datahat(:)).^2)/N);`
   This code (in the following order) reshapes `data` and `datahat` into a long, column vector, then performs the element-wise subtraction, element-wise raise to the power of 2 and finally the sum. Then it divides by `N` and evaluates the square root.
2. Mean Absolute Error (MAE)
   $MAE = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}|x_i-y_i|}{N}$
   In Matlab this will look like:
   `MAE=sum(abs(data(:)-datahat(:)))/N;`
   using the same notation as above.
3. Coefficient of Determination ($R^2$)
   $R^2 = \left( \dfrac{1}{N} \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i-\hat{x})(y_i-\hat{y})}{\sigma_t \sigma_e}\right) ^2$
   where $N$ is the number of estimated data points, $\sigma_t$ and $\sigma_e$ are the standard deviation of the true values and the estimated values (respectively),
   $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ are the mean value of the true and estimated values (respectively) and $x_i$ and $y_i$ have the same definition as above.

Now, regarding the problem. You cannot use any of these if your original dataset has missing values because in all of these parameter we need *true* values and *estimated* values.
So you can tackle the problem in two major ways:

- *create your own true dataset*
  Perform these steps (for any given interpolation technique):

  1. create a copy of your dataset in which you remove the data points with NaNs: in this manner your "true" data will be actual, non-missing values
  2. manually set some temperature values to NaN
  3. interpolate them using your preferred technique and then match the original value (before you turned it into NaN) with the estimated value
  4. use any of those three parameters to check its goodness
- *distribution matching*
  It is clear now that we need pairs of values to match (true and estimates) so you can fit your data to a given distribution (e.g. Gamma) and then match the distribution values with the estimated values.
  Main drawback is that you have to find a good distribution for your data and you must tune its parameters appropriately. You might want to check `fitdist()` in Matlab.

Regarding the correlation, you can use the `xcorr()` function that basically accepts two inputs (vectors) and returns the cross-correlation. You didn't explain any further about what correlations you do want to evaluate, but you can find the help page [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html) (with some examples as well).

**Update**: if you really want to use cross-validation in order to evaluate RMSE, you have to mix things up a bit. Let's start by having a look at `crossval()` (you can find the help page [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/crossval.html)).
As you can see you need to write a function `fun()` in order to evaluate the `testval` parameter (e.g. RMSE in your case).
Therefore `fun()` should interpolate the data first thanks to `interp2()` and then evaluate RMSE according to the formula above. This will be your `testval`.
As instead, `interp2()` is a function (you can find the help page [here](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html)) that can perform the interpolation according also to several methods (cubic, linear and so on).
So, in other words:

1. define a function (let's call it `myFun`) that interpolates the data and then evaluates (once the estimated data are known and taking into account that you always have the true values available) the RMSE according to the formula above
2. feed this function to `crossval()`, something like `myValues=crossval(@myFun,X);` where `X` is your dataset
3. enjoy `myValues`, that is your final output

and you might want to repeat such process for all the interpolation techniques you prefer in order then to select the technique that leads to the minimum RMSE.

Comment: thanks  @Alessiox.My data set is of climate parameters. In which there are some missing data(NaN) values in 3rd column(temperature). I have interpolated these NaN values through linear interpolation in matlab. Appearance of NaN value is randomly. I want to check whether linear interpolation will be best suited for my parameter or not. That why i search to cross validation. I want to divide my data set in randomly subsets( training and testing sets) . So that i can investigate whether this interpolation method was good for my data set or not? Please suggest me if  other approach is possible?

Comment: @MuhammadUsmanSaleem, If you really want to use `crossval()`, things are a little tricky. Please check my answer in a few minutes, I'll update with some useful infos.

Comment: Thanks for timely reply. I hope you able to understand my query well. Actually i have interpolated NaN values in this data set. And now i want to check with some authentic method whether my this interpolation is good or not.  Data is available in one text file not into two. And through this single file, we will create training and testing subset(randomly and will include NaN values). And then investigate whether interpolation is fine or not. PLZ SUGGEST IF OTHER WAY OF SOLVING MY QUERY IS POSSIBLE?

Comment: In order to provide batter assistance @Alessiox please check my edited question again

Comment: The RMSE looks like a good parameter in order to evaluate your model, I agree with you on that. However, you can try and perform the cross-validation according to the pseudo-code I provided but instead of `interp2()` you can as well use the scattered data interpolator. I mean, the interpolator (be it `interp2()` or your scattered) simply gives you the estimated data which you must use in the formula above for the RMSE.

Comment: i am getting confusion in your kind pseudonc code. As i requst humbly i am newer to matlab. Please note that i have only one text file not two. Please update..

Comment: It doesn't matter how many files you do have. As far as I understand you have the "true" temperatures and then you randomly remove some of those values and you try to estimate them using one of several interpolation techniques. Am I right? If you don't have the "true" temperature values you cannot possibly use RMSE and/or cross-validation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37588/discussion-between-muhammad-usman-saleem-and-alessiox).